# negative Coefficient interpretation

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have the following regression equation:

deathrate=0.237 (incidencerate)-0.0006(medincome)+0.201(pctpublicoverage)+0.0002(popest2015)-1.044(Private coverage )+0.777(private employeecovarge)+ ԑ

My interpretation for

```
Private coverage () – The coefficient of private coverage implies that 1 percentage point increase in the private coverage leads to decrease in the cancer mortality by 1.044.
```

My professor as to re-write my interpretation, He said that “ but a decrease by 104% implies negative mortality. We can’t have people rise from the dead. You need to think about if the numbers make sense (and realize that something is wrong with your first interpretation).”

I am not sure what does he mean, of course ppl are not rise form the death , it just mean that there is less death.

Can someone explain and provide the correct interpretation?

Thanks in adavcne.

Answer (score 0):

If deathrate was measured in percentage (I am pretty sure it was, but correct me if I am wrong), then you just forgot to use percentage points in your interpretation. It should have been: "... leads to decrease in the cancer mortality by 1.044 percentage points."

Comment: I think if that would have been the case if would have said that. But instead he says that "people cant be raise form the death" . is it because the coefficent is above 1 ?

Also, what does it mean precentage points?

Comment: But he did say. Without "percentage points" 1.044 is interpreted as 104%, and this kind of change implies that you will have a negative death rate: people rising from the dead. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point

Comment: Thank you! Misius.